# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 320

Tags: node.js

just wanted to ask why I am encountering this error. I would like to post the twitter new post to discord. Always stuck with this error and I dont know much about programming. Thanks.:

```
Node.js v17.1.0
I have no name!@4c5f33e2-a5a4-4959-b418-f20e3b503df6:~$ npm start
> discord.js-twitter-integration@3.0.0 start
> node index.js
undefined:13
        {
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 320
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
Node.js v17.1.0
```

Here is my code:

```
const wait = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);
const fs = require('fs');
const configfile = "./config.json";
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configfile, "utf8"));
```

Comment: Hello, can you put information on the config.json file?, since it is most likely that, seeing what you have indicated, it is badly formatted

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your config.json.

Posting the content of config.json may help for finding the error Generally it's a missing `"` or `,` or someting else

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
{
    "accounts": [
        {
            "twitter_name": "SomethingHere",
            "channel_id": "919590869420621895",
            "embed_color":"RANDOM"
        }
       
    ],
    "verbose": false,
    "retweet": true,
    "reply": false,
    "embed_color" : "RANDOM",

    "owner_id": "890585012671714587",
    "discord_token" : "CENSORED",
    "consumer_key": "CENSORED",
    "consumer_secret": "CENSORED",
    "access_token_key": "CENSORED",
    "access_token_secret": "CENSORED"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).